# New to wordpress. Need Help with templates

Tags: php, css

Alright greetings to everyone. I have been doing web development a lot lately, Usually Forums stuff but now I moved to Wordpress to advance further, So far I'm having a hard time. I have made my first theme but there is a lot of things I don't know how to. For example, 
**The blog page of my site has the same design as homepage, Which is not what I really want. Any help on how to design the blog page differently will be hugely appreciated.**

Also one more thing, I have something like this on my homepage designed :- 
https://gyazo.com/1f7e6476e1f054c92cb74a62622a9e3a

I would like to know if its possible to get the thumbnail and text from the latest blog posts.

Thanks a lot for all your help in regards

Comment: I think you should read some more about Wordpress and come back when you have a specific problem. Have you read [ask] already?

Comment: @Picard yes I have done the enough reading, I have skimmed through the theme handbook more than once. I have a vague idea about how to make templates now. However can you just explain me one thing. I have trouble understanding template hierarchy. What does the front-page.php does? Also should I have home.php if I have index.php? Its really confusing, Hope you understand that I'm just starting.

Answer (score 1):

> The blog page of my site has the same design as homepage

You are in a full control of design in theme. It only does what you code/style it to do.

For general direction you need to learn and understand how *templates* are named/selected and native *body classes* which WP applies and makes available for styling.

> I would like to know if its possible to get the thumbnail and text from the latest blog posts.

Yes, this is simple and staple functionality in many themes. You would want to start by looking up and learning how *post thumbnails* functionality works.